# Django serialize object return array

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Django serialize object return an array, and i cant get it in template with js

my view.py:

```
def MyExempleView(request):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", myModel.objects.all())
    context = {
        "data" : json.loads(data)
    }
    return render(request, 'consulta/myTemplateExemple.html', context=context)
```

my template:

```
{{ data|json_script:"data" }}

if ($("#data").length) {
    var data= JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').textContent);
}
```

my result exemple:

```
"[{"key": "value"}, {"key2": "value2"}]"
```

Comment: How do you *print* the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved loading and dumping the json with python json:

in views:

```
"data" : data
```

and in js in template:

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').textContent)
jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data)
```

Comment: Can't you omit the `json.dumps(json.loads(...))`, and thus work with `"data": data`?

Comment: i has been tried and doesn't it worked, and now work, tks

Comment: but normally `dumps` and `loads` are each other's inverse. So if both are removed, then one would expect that simply passing the data *without* any `dumps`/`loads`s would produce the same data.

Comment: this make sense now